# Unable to start mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I'm not able to start mariadb getting following error while starting db service.

```
root@server_name:~# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.9 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-01-05 20:07:46 CET; 16s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 2065 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1955 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]  
  Process: 1950 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1942 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2065 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jan 05 20:07:40 server_name systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.9 database server...
Jan 05 20:07:40 server_name mysqld[2065]: 2020-01-05 20:07:40 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.9-MariaDB-1:10.3.9+maria~xenial) start
Jan 05 20:07:46 server_name systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 05 20:07:46 server_name systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.9 database server.
Jan 05 20:07:46 server_name systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 05 20:07:46 server_name systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

```
############################# error log #####################################
#############################################################################

2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'myisam-recover' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'myisam-recover-options' instead.
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 100M, instances = 1, chunk size = 100M
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=109978330
2020-01-06 20:01:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 3951 pages from redo log.
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.9 started; log sequence number 118970057; transaction id 4809074
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2020-01-06 20:01:02 6 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2020-01-06 20:01:02 6 [ERROR] InnoDB: Column last_update in table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` is INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL but should be BINARY(4) NOT NULL (type mismatch).
2020-01-06 20:01:02 6 [ERROR] InnoDB: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table `mysql`.`gtid_slave_pos` but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.9-MariaDB-1:10.3.9+maria~xenial'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200106 20:01:02
2020-01-06 20:01:02 0x7f7b83fff700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/mariadb-10.3.9/storage/innobase/trx/trx0purge.cc line 121
InnoDB: Failing assertion: purge_sys.tail.commit last_commit
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-recovery-modes/
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
200106 20:01:02 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.9-MariaDB-1:10.3.9+maria~xenial
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=6
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 352708 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f7b700009a8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f7b83ffeb78 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x555d743edace]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x347)[0x555d73e938f7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f7bc7679390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7f7bc6c48428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f7bc6c4a02a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x49d7ea)[0x555d73bdd7ea]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xac09e0)[0x555d742009e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xac5d53)[0x555d74205d53]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xac6373)[0x555d74206373]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xaa7d65)[0x555d741e7d65]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f7bc766f6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f7bc6d1a41d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x0):
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` and see what messages are generated by mariadb starting. Also check out `mysql.err` just in case, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Add the contents of `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` to your question.

Comment: I had pasted error log in my question